# External javascript and jquery files are not loading when i am using server host name instead of DNS

Tags: javascript, server, dns

> When i am using server host name in the url, in that case the external
>   javascript and jquery files are not loading.

```
URL: http://10.212.653.65:61080/dma/reloadCacheAll.do?
```

> But when i am using the DNS, external files are getting loaded
>   successfully.

```
URL: http://www.example.com/dma/reloadCacheAll.do?
```

Comment: Are you sure `10.212.653.65` is the server host name? It looks like an (invalid) IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Please validate if you are able to resolve the IP with the FQDN. You can run 'NSLOOKUP' command to check if the IP resolves to the require FQDN or vice-versa.

Command -

> nslookup 10.212.653.65

or

> nslookup www.example.com

Comment: using http://was65as8-33.example.biz:61080dma/reloadCacheAll.do? instead of http://10.212.653.65:61080/dma/reloadCacheAll.do? also doesn't work.

Comment: Apologies if you are not able to get my point. You said www.example.com works for you instead of IP? correct me if I'm wrong here. If that is correct, then you need to validate if your DNS is able to resolve your IP correctly or not. If it doesn't then you need to correct the DNS entry for the affected IP